# TypeError when indexing numpy array using numba

Tags: python, numba

I need to sum up elements in a 1D `numpy` array (below: `data`) based on another array with information on class memberships (`labels`). I use `numba`in the code below to speed it up. However, If I dot not explicitly cast with `int()` in the line `ret[int(find(labels, g))] += y`, I reveice an error message:

`TypeError: unsupported array index type ?int64`

Is there a better workaround that explicit casting?

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jit

labels = np.array([45, 85, 99, 89, 45, 86, 348, 764])
n = int(1e3)
data = np.random.random(n)
groups = np.random.choice(a=labels, size=n, replace=True)

@jit(nopython=True)
def find(seq, value):
    for ct, x in enumerate(seq):
        if x == value:
            return ct

@jit(nopython=True)
def subsumNumba(data, groups, labels):
    ret = np.zeros(len(labels))
    for y, g in zip(data, groups):
        # not working without casting with int()
        ret[int(find(labels, g))] += y
    return ret
```

Comment: This code works with Numba 0.28.1 on my machine without error. What version of Numba are you using. Also as a side note, you might want to avoid using `zip` and `enumerate` and explicitly use an indexing counter for performance reasons. You'd have to test to see if it actually makes a difference for your use case, but in the past, in my experience, it does.

Comment: @JoshAdel I have version 0.26.0 (will try to update now). You mean the code works *without* int() casting on your machine?

Comment: @JoshAdel It tested function `find` without enumerate and the performance gain was minimal. I will keep it in mind when further optimizing the code.

Comment: @JoshAdel I upgraded to 0.28.1 and it still does not work without casting.

Comment: sorry, missed the cast. I added an official answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `find` can either return an `int` or `None` if it doesn't find anything, thus I think the `?int64` error. To avoid casting, you need to provide an `int` return value when `find` exits without finding the desired value and then handle it in the caller.

Comment: That's it! I didn't occur to me because `find` is guaranteed to find something be the structure of my problem. Now I just return a dummy integer for the theoretical case that there is not hit and it works!